# Caching data by creating a class is good?

Tags: c#, performance, caching, t4

We are building an workflow product.(ASP.NET 4.0, C# and SQL Server 2008) In that, We have about 20-30 tables that contains the workflow definition data, which will be used frequently during workflow execution also.

In order to increase the performance, we thought publishing the workflow definition data into a class(assembly) using T4 template. The class will be having all definition records as a properties and members and can be accessed easily and reduce the database hits.

I want to know this is approach is good. Or is there any alternate caching options available?

Comment: T4 templates build text files, and are useful in scaffolding, but I don't see any use in caching.

Comment: Classes are a good solution for this problem. But where does T4 come into play?

Comment: I think OP wants to automatically create the classes from the definitions, which are then used for caching. So whenever the definitions change, the classes are automatically updated and the updated classes can be used to cache the new data.

Comment: @poke, Yes. We have that same idea as you mentioned. I would like to know this is a good option or not.

Comment: It doesn’t sound too bad; and at least you are avoiding the need to manually update the classes in case the definitions change.

Comment: @poke As I said, we have 25-30 number of relational tables and we planned to create types(classes) for all the tables. Based on the hierarchy created classes can be nested too. We planned to use reflection to load and use the created classes.

I want to know whether any better alternate option available for this. Please let us know. Thanks in advance.....